# .NET Core ApiController-Attribute infers wrong binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I currently have a problem with the new .NET Core 2.1 attribute `[ApiController]` and I don't know how to solve it. If I apply the attribute I have problems with inference. Without everything works fine.

I have a controller with the `[ApiController]` attribute and an action that should accept a couple of different headers and a viewmodel.

The action looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyHeaderClass myHeaders, [FromBody]MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    var resultObject = await DoSomething();
    return Json("");
}
```

The MyHeadersClass looks like this:

```
public class MyHeadersClass 
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "X-Some-Id")]
    [Required]
    public string SomeId { get; set; }

    [FromHeader(Name = "X-SomeGuid-Id")]
    [Required]
    public Guid? SomeGuid { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to start my application it fails because .NET Core 2.1 tries to infer that `MyHeaderClass` is bound by request body.

The only thing that works is to apply the `[FromHeader]` attribute to my `MyHeaderClass` but then I have to specify a single header with

```
{
  X-Some-Id: string,
  X-SomeGuid-Id: string
}
```

But I want to have a single header for every property and that worked without the attribute. What could I change to get it working with the `[ApiController]` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to send your header info in the request body when you are marking your header with attribute **[FromHeader]**

> The only thing that works is to apply the [FromHeader] attribute to my
>   MyHeaderClass but then I have to specify a single header with
>
> ```
> {
>   X-Some-Id: string,
>   X-SomeGuid-Id: string
> }
> ```

I tested your code on .NET core 2.1 using POSTMAN it works fine with and without **[FromBody] Arttribute with [ApiController] present**.

Here is the Raw HTTP request from POSTMan with Header values in Header section and not in the Request Body:

```
POST /api/My/Register HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/json
X-Some-Id: idstring
X-SomeGuid-Id: guidstring

Postman-Token: 7fc48dc9-cb0b-46fd-8419-7ad4e3676855

{
    "username":"rajesh",
    "password":"password"
}
```

The point is you need to add header values in correct place in HTTP request as mentioned in HTTP request from POSTMAN Tool in below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to send my Header in the Request Body. The problem is that ASP.NET Core tries to infer that my MyHeaderClass should be sent in the Request Body and I don't want that. This only happens if I use the [ApiController] attribute.

Comment: @Shamshiel : "I don't want to send my Header in the Request Body.", Yes you are correct, you should not send your Header in Request Body, Rather you should send in the Header Section of your Request.  Can you share the code or how you are calling your API, that might help.